# datepicker multiple fields with logic to show month year only in few fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, logic

he all i am using this function of datepicker which is ok but what i want it to do is only on id datepicker1 full callender show with date month and year but for the rest ids datepicker2 till datepicker11 only month and year shows with the done button. would appreciate your help on it

here is the bit of my code

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7, #datepicker8, #datepicker9, #datepicker10,#datepicker11").addClass('datepicker');
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1947:" });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class `datepicker` to all datepicker ids except for `#datepicker1` and then do like:

```
$("#datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4, #datepicker5, #datepicker6, #datepicker7, #datepicker8, #datepicker9, #datepicker10,#datepicker11").addClass('datepicker');

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "M-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: "1947:"
});
$(".datepicker").focus(function() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
        my: "center top",
        at: "center bottom",
        of: $(this)
    });
});

$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
});
```

Comment: i tried this

$(".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "M-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "1947:" }); but did not work mate

Comment: bro its not working yes it now shows month and year to all ids including datepicker1 but clicking on the done button value does not get added to field

Comment: Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Just add `#datepicker1` & `#datepicker2` and let me know about the issue in fiddle.

Comment: here bro http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/8718/ also year not displaying for some reason

Comment: bro it seems perfect on jsfiddle but on my localhost it don seems to be working i wonder why even on datepicker1 i get just month and year only not whole callender

Comment: do you have `datepicker` class already added to the HTML markup for `#datepicker1`? I see you have this in code `input type="text" name="rdob" class="form-control input-lg datepicker" id="datepicker1" placeholder="Full Callender" value="" tabindex="2" />` just remove that class and try again.

Comment: bro thanks alot you really did me a great favor, very greatful to you :)

Comment: bro one small issue i face is when i click on datepicker2 even without selecting any value the current month and year gets added to form

Comment: Could you please post that as a new question? I am going offline now till then other users can help to figure it out. Also, add a demo fiddle it would help others to debug/figure out the issue fast.

Comment: Also, provide the question link here, if possible I will have a look into it.